# ANTLR4 : Accepting blank as a value/parameter

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I have implemented a function in ANTLR4.
Eg. - FUNCTION("A","B")

**Grammar** :

```
    parse
     : block EOF
     ;

    block
     : 'FUNCTION' LPAREN  (atom)? COMMA (atom)? LPAREN 
     ;

    atom
    :   NIL                         #nilAtom
     | list                         #arrayAtom
     | type=(INT | DOUBLE)          #numberAtom
     | ID                           #idAtom
     ;

    list
     : BEGL array? ENDL
     ;

    array
     : array_element ( COMMA array_element )* # arrayValues
     ;


    array_element
    :
        atom # array_element_types
    ;

    COMMA : ',';

    BEGL : '[';
    LPAREN : '(';

    RPAREN : ')';
    ENDL : ']';
    NIL : '' | 'null';
INT  : [0-9]+  ;

DOUBLE  : [0-9]+ '.' [0-9]*  | '.' [0-9]+ ;

COMMENT  : '#' ~[\r\n]* -> skip  ;

SPACE  : [ \t\r\n] -> skip  ;

OTHER  : .  ;
```

For input `FUNCTION(,"B")`, 
Not able to differentiate between first and second parameter.
Getting "B" as first parameter.
Thanks for help.

Comment: How do you recognize empty list (`[]`) from list with one blank element (`[]`)? Do you need to recognize those as different cases?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind interpreting `[]` as list with one blank element:

```
list
 : BEGL array ENDL
 ;

array
 : array_element ( COMMA array_element )* # arrayValues
 ;


array_element
:
    atom? # array_element_types
;
```

Comment: Agreed on this part. Lets say about function: FUNCTION(,"B") ,In this case, i need to know which is first and which is second parameter. But its giving only one parameter